# AC blowing hot air. Smart thermostat wiring wrong or something else?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, heat-pump, central-air

I installed a Honeywell Wi-Fi smart color 7 day programmable thermostat (model #RTH9585WF) on 11/27/23. The wiring directions on it didn't exactly match my old thermostat so I posted on a forum and someone clarified how it should be wired. (I believe it was the "W-O/B" that didn't match to my old thermostat, if I remember correctly.)
I tested the unit after install, and both cold and hot air worked fine. I can't say 100% that I've had the air on since 11/27, but have definitely had the heat on, which is why I'm asking about the wiring.

Tonight, the unit is blowing hot air. I replace my filters every 60-90 days max, I checked the coils and they're not frozen over, and I verified the outside fan is running so it's not the start capacitor. I'm hoping someone can double check that I didn't mess up the wiring, or maybe offer another suggestion as to what could be wrong? Thanks for any help!

The first pic is the wiring of the old thermostat, the second pic is the new one.

EDITED: It is a heat pump system, and I'm in Florida, USA.

[image: This is the old thermostat]

[image: This is the new thermostat]

Comment: Can you clarify?  A/C with no furnace?  Not a heat pump?  *Hot,* not ambient temp?  Are you in the southern hemisphere?

Comment: Sorry, it is a heat pump. I'm in Florida. And it was definitely pumping hot air, not ambient.

Comment: The deal is that with a heat pump, the heater and the A/C *are the same thing*.   It's really weird, and here's a video series on it.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7J52mDjZzto&list=PLv0jwu7G_DFVIot1ubOZdR-KC-LFdOVqi

Comment: Thanks for the video link. I do understand what a heat pump is; they're incredibly common in Florida. Unfortunately that doesn't address the problem of why my AC system is pumping heated air when it's set to cool.

Comment: Sounds like you have a reversing valve issue.  Could be the 'stat, could be the way it's wired up.  Is there a setting that you can swap O/B?

Comment: I had someone come out, and it ended up being the wire that energizes the reversing valve was damaged and needed to be spliced. It's resolved now.